# How to make a function to be a slot temporally in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, slot

To make a function of a class to be a slot, the class has to inherit from QObject. However, QObject takes up a quite large amount of memory. I am not sure how much it is and if the memory is for each class or each object. My code has many small data whose functions can be a slot sometime. I am wonder if there is a way to make a function of class to be a slot temporally when using it. After using it, the memory for the slot cost will be deleted. The following code illustrates the requirement.

```
class SmallData // size of 2 or 3 integers.
{
public:
    virtual void F(); // use it as a slot.
    virtual QMenu* createMenu(); // use this to create the context menu with
                                 // an action connected to F()
    ...
};

// use the small data
vector<SmallData> vec(1000000); // the vector is put at a tree view. When an
                                // item in the tree view is selected, a context
                                // menu pop up with an action to run F().
SmallData* data = treeView.selectedItem();    
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), data, SLOT(F())); // How to make F() to be
                                                       // a slot just here.
                                                       // The action is from 
                                                       // data->createMenu().
```

Comment: What makes you think QObject takes up a quite large amount of memory?

Comment: I checked it but not very carefully. It has a parent pointer and other data to implement its mechanism.

Comment: That's not possible. Also, with a million items, using item-based models instead of a custom QAbstractItemModel will be your bottleneck, not just QObjects. Add a single slot, look up the selected SmallData objects, call F() on them.

Comment: @aschepler Well, it has all kinds of magical things, like a name, a parent, Qt's own RTTI, some flags. Those things will probably outweight this `SmallData` thing by some factor. Of course one might regard this as premature optimization. But then again a million such things isn't that insignificant an amount and we shouldn't prematurely allocate memory for stuff we never ever gonna need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use Qt5, you can [connect signals to plain functions and static methods](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) (which essentially are funnily named plain functions):

```
connect(action, &QAction::triggered, 
        &SmallData::statF);
```

Where `action` is a `QAction` instance, and `SmallData::statF` is a static method of `SmallData`.

Edit per Christian Rau's comment, to call a particular instance, you can also connect to lambda:

```
connect(action, &QAction::triggered,
        [data]() { data->F(); });
```

Already with Qt4, you can use [`QSignalMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html#details) to achieve much the same effect, with a few more objects. It allows you to add add a parameter (in this case, probably an integer index to your `vec`) to signal, based on which object emitted it. But in Qt4, receiver must still always be a QObject.

Comment: If this works, it will be the simplest solution. My SmallData::stateF is virtual and not static. Any way to do it?

Comment: +1 Wow, now that is nice (haven't had so many looks at the new Qt yet). Might be even used together with C++11's functional facilities to avoid static stuff: `connect(action, &QAction::triggered, std::bind(&SmallData::F, data));`. If this works (they at least speak about `tr1::bind` being supported) and you could add it, then that's the IMHO best answer available.

Comment: @user1899020 Unfortunately method pointers are not supported (as far as I know). If you want a method of particular object instance to be called, it must be a QObject instance. QSignalMapper allows you to pass differenet parameter based on which QObject emitted the signal though, maybe that is of help to you.

Comment: @hyde See my comment, you can at least use `tr1::bind` (though I guess `std::bind` should work, too) or a capturing lambda (`connect(action, &QAction::triggered, [data]() { data->F(); });`), no need for any static rubbish.

Answer (score 3):

For using the signal slot mechanism, you won't get around `QObject`, but what you can do is create a temporary object that has a slot calling your function. You just have to care for properly releasing the object. Something like:

```
class Callback : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    typedef std::function<void()> FunctionType;

    Callback(FunctionType fn, bool oneShot = true, QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject(parent), fn_(std::move(fn)), oneShot_(oneShot) {}

public slots:
    void call()
    {
        fn_();        //delegate to callback
        if(oneShot_)
            deleteLater();  //not needed anymore
    }

private:
    FunctionType fn_;
    bool oneShot_;
};

Callback* makeCallback(FunctionType fn, bool oneShot = true, QObject *parent = nullptr)
{
    return new Callback(std::move(fn), oneShot, parent);
}
```

You then just create a (more or less temporary) `Callback` object each time needed:

```
SmallData* data = treeView.selectedItem();
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), 
        makeCallback(std::bind(&SmallData::F, data)), SLOT(call()));
```

With the `oneShot` parameter you can control if the slot should dissolve automatically once triggered.

The only problem is, if this slot is never called, you have a leaking `Callback` hanging around. To accomodate this, you can pass something meaningful into the `parent` argument, so that Qt cares for proper deletion at least at some later point in time:

```
SmallData* data = treeView.selectedItem();
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), 
        makeCallback(std::bind(&SmallData::F, data), true, this), SLOT(call()));
```

This way you can also bind the lifetime of the callback object (and thus the signal-slot connection) to some other object (e.g. the action itself and deleting the action when no item is selected, or something the like).

Alternatively, you can also remember the `Callback` object for the currently selected item and care for proper deletion yourself, once it's delesected.

**disclaimer:** Beware that the above example contains plenty of C++11, but I'm not in the mood to rewrite this for C++03. Likewise can this solution be imporved further, maybe using a templated functor instead of a `std::function` (but if I remember correctly the Qt meta object system doesn't like templates that much).

---

**EDIT:** In the end the solution proposed by *Frank Osterfeld* in his comment might be a much simpler approach for your situation than my overly generic object lifetime madness above: Just connect the action to a single slot of a higher level object (your main widget or maybe the item model containing the data vector) and call `F` on the currently selected item:

```
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(callF()));
...
void MyController::callF()
{
    treeView.selectedItem()->F();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you try to do is possible in Qt.

If you really don't want to inherit QObject, then I suggest you have a look at the [boost signals and slots mechanism](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/signals2.html).